# ng-click Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular Directive with isolated scope, with one div which sometimes is clickable (div with ng-click is rendered), sometimes not (div without ng-click is rendered)

How can I test if my directive contains a clickable div?
I can't find a good example for it.